# is it possible to run SqlDependency in node js or any other programming language (without .NET)?

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, real-time

we need real time [realtime](/questions/tagged/realtime) table data change notification in node js app without using a trigger.
so there is any alternative  way to achieve  real time query notification [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) in node js or any other programming language (without .NET) ?

we are used tedious and mssql project to get real time change notification in nodejs
SqlDependency [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) is not working in node js so there is any alternative way to achive these ?

````
const { Connection, Request } = require('tedious');
const config = {
    server: 'localhost',
    authentication: {
        type: 'default',
        options: {
            userName: 'sa',
            password: 'test'
        }
    },
    options: {
        database: 'TestQueryNotifications',
        trustServerCertificate: true,
        rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion: true,
        enableServiceBroker: true,
        encrypt: false
    }
};
const connection = new Connection(config);

connection.on('connect', (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        return;
    }

    console.log('Connected to SQL Server.');
    const query = 'SELECT * FROM my_test_table';
    const request = new Request(query, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
            return;
        }
        console.log('Query completed.');
        //connection.close();
    });
    request.on('notification', (notification) => {
        console.log('Query notification received.');
        console.log(notification);
    });
    connection.execSql(request);
});

connection.connect();```
````

Comment: There are a number of restrictions for a query in order to receive notifications. The query is invalid because 1) it specifies `SELECT *` instead of an explicit column list and 2) the table name is not schema-qualified (e.g. `dbo.mytable`). See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms181122(v=sql.105)) for a list of limitations and restrictions.

Comment: @DanGuzman  thank you, I changed query `const query = 'SELECT random_text FROM dbo.my_test_table';` but real-time query notification is not working in node js.